# Universal way to temporarily reverse boot order with bcdedit.exe

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcdedit

### Situation

I've got two boot-configurations. Let's say the UUID's are {1234} and {4321}.

Default is {1234}

### What I want

When {1234} is booted, I want to switch the boot order from {1234} {4321} to {4321} {1234} but just for one boot. So I want to reverse boot order for the next time the computer boots up. The problem is that I don't know the UUID's. Because the "Script" that I'm trying to write has to work on multiple computers, where the UUID's obviously are going to differ.

### What I tried

```
bcdedit.exe /bootsequence {current} /addlast
```

and

```
bcdedit.exe /bootsequence {default} /addlast
```

These commands did not work obviously. Another solution I could imagine is to query the UUID's. Is there a reliable way to get the UUID's and as well to check which one is booted? Or does anyone know a command for my specific needs?

### Another way to ask the question:

Given two boot-configurations. When the default one is booted, I want to boot 'the other configuration' with the next restart (and only with the next restart). But I don't have the UUID of 'the other configuration'.

Comment: `Is there a reliable way to get the UUID's and as well to check which one is booted?`: `bcdedit /enum osloader /v` and `bcdedit /enum {current} /v`?

Comment: I use easy BCD for this, it is free, no need to register just hit the download button...http://neosmart.net/Download/Register

Comment: @TomYan It has to be programmatically reliable. Sorry for not being clear about it.

Comment: @Moab Does it support the command line? Have not found anything about it on their website. I need to use is in a PowerShell script.

Comment: unfortunately it is gui only, sorry I could not help.